# Git bash работа с новым проектом

Tags: git-branch, git-bash

Работал впервый раз над проектом в git bash, мог что-то наложать с ветками, сейчас когда пытаюсь создать новый проект меня сразу закидывает на ветку с прошлого проекта как только начинаю в новой папке. На этом проекте вообще не должно быть веток, пробовал reset clean , даже когда нахожусь на рабочем столе в расположении остается эта ветка. Как удалить её или начать новый проект что б не высвечивалась эта ветка. То есть при перемещении в гите по папкам у меня всегда подсвечивает что эти файлы находятся на этой ветке

Comment: добавь в вопрос какие команды вводишь, что выводится в ответ. Телепатов тут нет. Но вообще - каждый проект должен быть в отдельной папке

Comment: создал новую папку в которой еще ничего нет, включаю git-bash, захожу в эту новую папку а на ней уже ветка есть, при git-status выдает удаленные раньше объекты с другого проекта

Comment: что еще ввести что б сделать проверку, git branch показывает что эта ветка есть даже когда нахожусь на рабочем столе

Comment: создал новую папку ГДЕ?

Comment: @Эникейщик , что еще нужно прописать, судя по тому что написал раньше, эта ветка находилась глобально или я её как-то вынес вне ветки master

Comment: на рабочем столе

Comment: ты б еще написал "в компьютере"... Как эта папка расположена относительно другого проекта.

Comment: на рабочем столе была папка с проектом в котором я работал, эта папка уже давно в архивах, создаю новую папку на рабочем столе но на неё вешается ветка

Comment: значит у тебя на рабочем столе есть папка .git. Удали ее и вообще не храни проекты на рабочем столе. И корневой папкой для прошлого проекта был именно рабочий стол, а не папка, в которой был проект.

Comment: @Эникейщик получилось, спасибо большое, я разобрался , и спасибо за совет, сделай свой комментарий ответом что б я мог отметить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По симптомам похоже, что вы пытаетесь создать проект внутри существующего репозитория git.

Это легко проверить выполнив команду `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` находясь в вашей новой папке.

Если вы вне репозитория, то получите ошибку `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`, если же внутри, то вам будет выведена папка являющаяся корнем репозитория, содержащая каталог `.git`.

Или новый проект нужно будет создавать вне этой папки, или, если репозиторий был создан там случайно, то переместите папку `.git` существующего репозитория в другое место. Или полностью удалите, если это был тренировочный репозиторий.